# Storing primary key of Relational database in document of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, oracle, database-design, primary-key

Suppose, I have a table (customers) in Oracle with column names as **customer_id(PK)**, customer_name, customer_email, customer address. And I have a collection (products) in MongoDB which is storing customer_id as one of its field. Below, is a sample of document in products collection, which is storing **customer_id "customer123"**, which is primary key in customers table in Oracle database.

```java
{
_id : "product124",
customer_id: "customer123",
product_name: "hairdryer"
}
```

My questions is, Is it a good idea to use different types of databases when one field like customer_id here is shared between them. Is it a good practice in enterprises level development?

Please ignore the use case, as I am just trying to give a simple example to provide better understanding of the problem.

Comment: it's very open-ended question. "the best tool for the job" they say. If the job is big you may need many tools. It really depends on the use case, and even then it's too opinion based to SO standards. Can you rephrase your question to highlight what are your concerns.

Comment: If `customer_id` is a primary key, then *not* storing it in Oracle is not an option. Conversely, customer_id appears to be used as a foreign key in your Mongo DB database, so *not* storing it there doesn't really work either. It appears that there is a specific *reason* that data is present in both locations. How would you envision only storing it in one location if it is needed in both, or even used to join tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is acceptable to use different databases in distributed systems and keep references between entities, but it really depends on the use case. If you plan to perform frequent and heavy joins between these 2 entities then storing them in separated databases (especially of different types) might dramatically affect your performance. However, if your use case does not require frequent relations resolving, this approach could work. But bear in mind that you need to consider the future scale of your application and how would this architectural decision affect the potential growth.